# WPF Attached Property's Type is being mangled by framework

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

Consider pretty much standard Attached Property for some derived type:

```
public class DerivedKeyBinding : KeyBinding
{
    public string Name; //shortened, make this propdp
}

public class KeyBindingExtenstions
{
    public static DerivedKeyBinding GetCommand(DependencyObject obj) {
        return (DerivedKeyBinding)obj.GetValue(CommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject obj, DerivedKeyBinding value) {
        obj.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", typeof(DerivedKeyBinding), typeof(KeyBindingExtenstions), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, CommandChanged));

    private static void CommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var commandValue = GetCommand(d);
    }
}
```

which is later set in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="local:KeyBindingExtenstions.Command">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <local:DerivedKeyBinding Name="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

This will, however, crash on the `var commandValue = GetCommand(d);` line due to `local:DerivedKeyBinding` lost to `KeyBinding` somewhere in process.
For some weird reason the property of `DerivedKeyBinding` type is being set with value of type `KeyBinding` (even though value is *explicitly* set to `DerivedKeyBinding` in XAML).

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Input.KeyBinding' to type 'AttachedPropertyInStyle.DerivedKeyBinding'.'

Why is this happening and how can I fix the issue?

---

The issue seems to be connected to the `Name` binding - if it is static value, the code executes flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override [`Key​Binding.​Create​Instance​Core`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keybinding.createinstancecore?view=netframework-4.8). From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable.createinstancecore?view=netframework-4.8#notes-to-inheritors):

> **Notes to Inheritors**
>
> Every Freezable derived class must implement this method. A typical implementation is to simply call the default constructor and return the result.

---

```
public class DerivedKeyBinding : KeyBinding
{
    ...

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new DerivedKeyBinding();
    }
}
```

In the PropertyChangedCallback you may also write:

```
var commandValue = (DerivedKeyBinding)e.NewValue;
```

Comment: Well, it seems I need to find some kind of manual "Derving framework classes 101". Thanks for the answer.